# How to use simple_form to submit a form to database in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I have a blog app that uses Devise for auth. I want users to be able to have a profile, how would I do that using the `simple_form` gem?

I tried:

```
rails g controller AuthorProfiles

rails g migration add_author_profile_to_users description:text
```

Comment: What are you looking to add in the profile?

Comment: @hashrocket some text like description and stuffs

Comment: You can add this directly to Devise. You don’t necessarily need another controller.

Comment: What migration do I have to run?

Answer (score 0):

You can add your new parameters directly to Devise. When the user goes to edit their profile, you can add the additional parameters there and they can fill them out or change them. Check out the [docs](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#strong-parameters).